# PhoneGap script not working in mobile build

Tags: phonegap-build

As am create a PhoneGap application it's work in the desktop browser with validation. when am convert the mobile build the script not working.

Comment: What is your question? What does your code look like? What result do you expect, and what result do you get?

Comment: am create a simple PhoneGap application.it work's in chrome browser with jquery validation. and am converting a mobile build apk and install the phone.now my validation script not working in the app